# How can I specify maximum cache-time for any data matching a regex in apollo-client with InMemoryCache?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-server

Some fields coming from the graphql server will have the shape `short-lived-token-XYZ123`.  Ideally we wouldn't even have to know the field names ahead of time, as any code we write will live in a library.  How can I hook into the InMemoryCache or the ApolloClient object to set the cache time of fields with values matching a regex?  Causing them to poll at a set interval would be really ideal, but because polling is query-centric, I dont think that is possible at the field level.  Giving them a specific cache time would be enough. Is there a way to hook into the InMemoryCache with a function that gets called on every read?

Another option would be to make these token strings a graphql type `Token` like

```
type Token {
    id: String
}
```

and then in the client it might be possible to define a custom cache behavior for this type when initializing the cache like

```js
new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Token: {
      fields: {
        id: {
          read(cachedVal) {
            if (cacheTimeElapsed){
                return null
            } else {
                return cachedVal
            }
           
          }
        }
      },
    },
  },
```

But Im also unclear HOW to bust the cache using the read function.  What do I return from the function to tell the cache that it is busted and needs to refetch?  These docs are...challenging.  If I could just call a function on every single read and do what I need to do, that would be ideal.

These fields will also be annotated in the apollo-server with `@token`(for other reasons), and we could potentially hook in here to somehow tell the client to cache-bust these fields.  Not sure how, but it's another option.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same question on the Apollo forums and received the answer that, remarkably, they don't support setting specific cache times or invalidating the cache from the `read` function of the typePolicies.  It is  apparently on the roadmap.

A third party caching library was suggested instead:  https://github.com/NerdWalletOSS/apollo-cache-policies

Looking in the "Why does this exist?" in the NerdWallet README, you can see they mention that this is a common pain point with the InMemoryCache